# How to select more than one matching data in MongoDB using Nodejs in Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

this is the code to find one matching data which works fine. But when i replace `db.findOne({username: email}` with `db.find({username: email}` I cannot see all the values with the specific email id.

This is my code to connect to the mongo database

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; 
var db;
var connected = false;
/**Connects to the MongoDB Database with the provided URL**/
exports.connect = function(url, callback) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, _db) {
    if (err) { throw new Error('Could not connect: ' + err); }
    db = _db;     
    connected = true;     
    console.log(connected + " is connected?");
    callback(db);
  });
};

/**Returns the collection on the selected database**/   
exports.collection = function(name) {
  if (!connected) {
    throw new Error('Must connect to Mongo before calling  "collection"');   
  }    
  return db.collection(name);   
};
```

How can I access all the data related to a email id? Please help.. I am new to Mongodb

Comment: The mongodb connection code is not particularly helpful/relevant if you're saying that `db.findOne` is working for you. Could you please share the schema for the model you're trying to query, as well as the function using `db.find` that you're trying to debug?

Comment: function db.find is inbuilt and not implemented by me. db is initialized to the collection that i want to access. how would you suggest me to access data if db.findOne is not the right way. Thanks

Comment: You should really add these to your original post rather than in comments, but I was asking for the function that *uses* `db.find`, not `db.find` itself. At least as far as you've described, you seem to be using `db.find` correctly, so the problem must be elsewhere. Also, I'd advise not posting passwords on public forums!